# How to call static constructor outside class?

Tags: c#, .net, static

I was asked in interview :

```
public class Test
{
    static Test(){}
}

public class Class1 
{
    //Call static constructor Here
}
```

I Tried to call static constructor inside base class constructor . but this does not seems in right direction. How do you do it?

Comment: Static constructor calls implicitly, when you accessing any static property or method or on instance creation.

Comment: Access any other static member of the class or create an instance of the class and *if nothing else has caused it to happen already* than the static constructor will be called. You should never need to force this to happen.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot call a static constructor, and you cannot specify its visibility (`public`)

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class
>   before the first instance is created or any static members are
>   referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Static constructors are called automatically before any usage of a class and not supposed to be called manually so the correct answer is to do something on the `Test` class like :

```
public class Class1 
{
    public void CallStaticConstructorHere()
    {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

But 99% of the time you shouldn't care, the runtime will call it when needed.

In some case (like forcing some initialization during startup so that it doesn't happens latter during application use, or in the SetUp of some unit tests) you might need to force it.

The class [`RuntimeHelpers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provide this capability:

```
public class Class1 
{
    public void CallStaticConstructorHere()
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Test).TypeHandle);
    }
}
```

PS: *The name `RunClassConstructor` is misleading it run it only if it didn't already run*

PS(2): I don't know the exact question but if the interviewer was speaking of a Base class constructor (`Class1 : Test`) it is useless as no code in the derived class will ever be called without the base class static constructor being called before.

Comment: +1 to VBFox for the RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor

Answer (score 1):

Static constructors are not to be called explicitly, they are initialized before the first instance is created therefore cannot be sent parameters

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft states

> A static constructor cannot be called directly.

Referance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

While you can not call static constructor directly (as everybody knows), you can make sure what is it called... by accessing that class from.. static constructor (which should make statement `call static constructor here` valid if there are no other static constructors what accessing that class) << I may get down-votes from those who will not understand written in brackets =D

```
public class Test
{
    static Test(){}
}

public class Class1 
{
    //Call static constructor Here
    static Class1()
    {
        // yes sir!
        var test = new Test();
    }
}
```